# ASP.Net with IE10 "This page can't be displayed"

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

when i try to browes my ASP.Net Application with IE version 10 this message displayed:
"This page can't be displayed"
I don't know where the problem and how can i check the problem

I use ASP.Net 4.0

Comment: Seems more like an IE issue. Have you checked the IE settings or googled for the answer?

Comment: did you checked it on other browsers? May be problem is different rather then IE.

Comment: I checked it on other browsers and other IE Versions and its OK